Generate access tokens after successful social login with Google
I am implementing a spring authorization server with Spring Security 6. Simple authentication of users registered in a local database is already implemented and generating access tokens perfectly.
I need to implement social login using Google as an authentication provider, but I need access tokens to continue to be generated by my authorization server, that is, the Google service will only be responsible for the login and when the authorization server receives a positive response from Google, will use the username to search the local database for authorities and other user data to generate the token and thus return this token to the client.
I couldn't find any examples that would help me accomplish this task, so I would greatly appreciate any help.
NOTE: I have already configured the Google account and can now communicate with the authorization server.
My Security Filter Chain Configuration
  @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(oidc -> oidc
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.userInfoMapper(userInfoMapper()))
                        .logoutEndpoint(withDefaults()));

        http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(FORM_LOGIN_URL)))
                .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain oauth2SecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage(FORM_LOGIN_URL).permitAll())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.loginPage(FORM_LOGIN_URL).permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_ENDPOINT)
                        .logoutSuccessUrl(FORM_LOGIN_URL)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true));

        return http.build();
    }


When you're configuring the authorization server, you need to specify a redirect URI for the social login provider. According to the Spring Authz Server docs, this redirect URI template is similar to this:
{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}, where the registrationId is a unique identifier for the social client you specify when configuring the authz server.
When your social provider completes authentication, it will redirect you to this redirect URI with authenticated user's info. What you can do is, create a controller for this endpoint and handling your use cases here.
Eg:
You can retrieve the authentication from:
var authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Then you can check if this authentication is an instance of OAuth2AuthenticationToken and fetch the registrationId and the principalName from it. You can use these two to call the OAuth2AuthorizedClientService and obtain an access token.
var authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
        oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oauthToken.getName()
    ); // You can autowire OAuth2AuthorizedClientService
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();

    return accessToken;
}

You can refer to this GitHub repo for a sample implementation. (Disclaimer: code is not written by me). There maybe other ways to implement the same with SecurityFilterChain, so you may want to explore those as well. You also can refer to this Medium article for further reference.

Have you read the Spring Security documentation for OAuth2 Login? It walks you through the configuration options for Google Login which you should be able to use and secure the appropriate endpoints you already have to generate your own authorization token.
They also have a sample application that you can look at here.
I don't quite understand your use case but I'm imagining you have an endpoint that is returning access tokens that is secured by google so following the sample should give you that ability. Once you receive the access token from that endpoint, the other endpoint that you have working already I'm supposing is secured by generated token.

Thanks for your answer. My use case is: I need to use Google as a login provider, but the access token that the client will get in response to a successful login must be generated by Authz Server itself instead of the token provided by Google.

Got you.  If that is the case, the answer provided by Suvin is closer to what you are looking for.
